# Uncompress problem and ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently working on this problem called Uncompress:

```
Write a function, uncompress, that takes in a string as an argument. The input string will be formatted into multiple groups according to the following pattern:

<number><char>

for example, '2c' or '3a'.
The function should return an uncompressed version of the string where each 'char' of a group is repeated 'number' times consecutively. You may assume that the input string is well-formed according to the previously mentioned pattern.
```

And I hit a pretty interesting error on the last spec,

```
import unittest
from problems import uncompress

class TestUncompress(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_uncompress(self):
        string = "2c3a1t"
        expected = "ccaaat"
        actual = uncompress.uncompress(string)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

def test_uncompress_2(self):
    string = "4s2b"
    expected = "ssssbb"
    actual = uncompress.uncompress(string)
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

def test_uncompress_3(self):
    string = "2p1o5p"
    expected = "ppoppppp"
    actual = uncompress.uncompress(string)
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
    
def test_uncompress_4(self):
    string = "3n12e2z"
    expected = "nnneeeeeeeeeeeezz"
    actual = uncompress.uncompress(string)
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
    
def test_uncompress_5(self):
    def helper(value):
        return ''.join(['y' for _ in range(value)])
    string = "127y"
    expected = helper(127)
    actual = uncompress.uncompress(string)
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

Which is the error on the title, `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'`

I only get this error with this code,

```
def uncompress(string):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    values = []
    while right < len(string):
        if string[left] == string[right]:
            right += 1
        else:
            number = int(string[left: right])
            values.append(number * string[right])
            right += 1
            left = right
    return ''.join(values)
```

But if I do this, then the error goes away and it runs just fine.

```
def uncompress(string):
    numbers = '123456789'
    left = 0
    right = 0
    values = []
    while right < len(string):
        if string[right] in numbers:
            right += 1
        else:
            number = int(string[left: right])
            values.append(number * string[right])
            right += 1
            left = right
    return ''.join(values)
```

So I am kind of confused with what the error is and what is generating it, from those 2 code snippets, the only thing I changed was the `if statement`, so I'm not sure what the issue is.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the code yourself?

The second `uncompress` function is fine.

Now, it looks like your first `uncompress` function is rather a mix of a compress and uncompress, in particular the comparison `if string[left] == string[right]:` is really what one would do to check consecutive characters.

An indeed, only a few changes make it a compress function (`aabbccc` -> `2a2b3c`):

```
def compress(string):
    left = 0
    right = 0
    values = []
    while right < len(string):
        if string[left] == string[right]:
            right += 1
        else:
            number = len(string[left: right])            ## changed
            values.extend([str(number), string[left]])   ## changed
            right += 1
            left = right
    number = len(string[left: right])                    ## changed
    values.extend([str(number), string[left]])           ## changed
    return ''.join(values)
```

example:

```
>>> compress('zzyyyy')
2z3y
```

Comment: Yes I wrote both solutions and the test cases, it works fine for the other test cases, but for that large one for 127y it complains about the base 10. So it is just for that one that fails, so I was wondering what the issue is.

Comment: I have a working solution, and I have done the Compress version as well, but I was wondering about what that error is, and why changing those 2 lines make it "break".